# How can I pad a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, padding

Is there some easy way to pad Strings in Java?

Seems like something that should be in some StringUtil-like API, but I can't find anything that does this.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Apache [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) has several methods: [`leftPad`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int)), [`rightPad`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad(java.lang.String,%20int)), [`center`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#center(java.lang.String,%20int)) and [`repeat`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int)).

But please note that — as others have mentioned and demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391978/1725096) — `String.format()` and the `Formatter` classes in the JDK are better options. Use them over the commons code.

Comment: java.util.Formatter (and String.format()) does this.  Always prefer the JDK to an external library if the JDK version does the job (which it does).

Comment: For several reasons, I'd now prefer Guava to Apache Commons; [this answer shows how to do it in Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7502863/56285).

Comment: @Jonik would you care to list some of your reasons? The APIs look pretty much the same.

Comment: @glen3b: For an individual utility, like these string padding helpers, it really makes no difference which lib to use. That said, Guava is overall a more modern, cleaner and better documented lib than its counterparts in various Apache Commons projects (Commons Lang, Commons Collections, Commons IO, etc). It's also built by really smart guys (Kevin Bourrillion et al), many of whom are [active at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/guava/topusers). Myself I ended up replacing the various Apache Commons libs with just Guava years ago, and have had no regrets.

Comment: @glen3b: Some good [further reading at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542550/what-are-the-big-improvements-between-guava-and-apache-equivalent-libraries).

Comment: `StringUtils`/`Strings` is still the better choice IMO when the size of the pad is a runtime variable.

Answer (score 734):

Since Java 1.5, [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) can be used to left/right pad a given string.

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
     return String.format("%-" + n + "s", s);  
}

public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%" + n + "s", s);  
}

...

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
 System.out.println(padRight("Howto", 20) + "*");
 System.out.println(padLeft("Howto", 20) + "*");
}
```

And the output is:

```
Howto               *
               Howto*
```

Comment: What if you need to lpad with other chars (not spaces) ? Is it still possible with String.format ?  I am not able to make it work...

Comment: AFAIK String.format() can't do that but it's not too difficult to code it, see http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0448.html (2nd example)

Comment: @Nullw0rm, if you're referring to rgagnon.com, be aware that RealHowTo is the author of rgagnon.com too, so he would be crediting himself...

Comment: at least on my JVM, the "#" doesn't work, the "-" is fine. (Just delete the #). This may be consistent with the formatter documentation, I dunno; it says "'#' '\u0023'  Requires the output use an alternate form. The definition of the form is specified by the conversion."

Comment: WIth jre6, "%1$#" is ok but with jre7 "%1$#" throws java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = #.  I have updated this answer by removing the "#".

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. I have a doubt though, what is the `1$` for? @leo has made a very similar answer that doesn't use `1$` and it apparently has the same effect. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Oh of course it is to explicitly force argument order of String.format, sorry for the stupid question. `:P` Even then, it serves virtually no use in this case, I assume.

Comment: Note that `n` _must_ be greater than `0`.

Comment: Since Java 11, use String.repeat, see below the answer by Eko Setiawan.

Comment: Can I zero-pad something that is not a number?

Answer (score 295):

Padding to 10 characters:

```
String.format("%10s", "foo").replace(' ', '*');
String.format("%-10s", "bar").replace(' ', '*');
String.format("%10s", "longer than 10 chars").replace(' ', '*');
```

output:

```
  *******foo
  bar*******
  longer*than*10*chars
```

Display '*' for characters of password:

```
String password = "secret123";
String padded = String.format("%"+password.length()+"s", "").replace(' ', '*');
```

output has the same length as the password string:

```
  secret123
  *********
```

Comment: Just as long as we all remember not to pass in a string with spaces... :D

Comment: I'm with @aboveyou00--this is a horrendous solution for strings with spaces, including the example provided by leo. A solution for padding a string on the left or the right should not alter the input string as it appears in the output, unless the input string's original padding causes it to exceed the specified padding length.

Comment: Acknowledge the space issue. `.replace(' ', '*')` was rather intended to show the effect of padding. The password hiding expression does not have this issue anyway... For a better answer on customizing the left and right padding string using native Java feature see my other answer.

Comment: If the string contains only single spaces and you want to pad with different characters, you can use regex replace with look behind/ahead: `String.format("%30s", "pad left").replaceAll("(?<=( |^)) ", "*")` or `String.format("%-30s", "pad right").replaceAll(" (?=( |$))", "*")`

Answer (score 87):

In [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), this is easy:

```
Strings.padStart("string", 10, ' ');
Strings.padEnd("string", 10, ' ');
```

Comment: Adding 2.7MB code dependency for just a padding that's already included in the standard JDK? Seriously.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of these methods in `Guava` source, this stupid short-circuiting makes them almost unusable: `if (string.length() >= minLength) { return string; }`  :(

Answer (score 44):

**Something simple:**

The value should be a string. convert it to string, if it's not. Like `"" + 123` or `Integer.toString(123)`

```
// let's assume value holds the String we want to pad
String value = "123";
```

Substring start from the value length char index until end length of padded:

```
String padded="00000000".substring(value.length()) + value;

// now padded is "00000123"
```

**More precise**

pad right:

```
String padded = value + ("ABCDEFGH".substring(value.length())); 

// now padded is "123DEFGH"
```

pad left:

```
String padString = "ABCDEFGH";
String padded = (padString.substring(0, padString.length() - value.length())) + value;

// now padded is "ABCDE123"
```

Answer (score 29):

Have a look at `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#rightPad(String str, int size, char padChar)`.

But the algorithm is very simple (pad right up to size chars):

```
public String pad(String str, int size, char padChar)
{
  StringBuilder padded = new StringBuilder(str);
  while (padded.length() < size)
  {
    padded.append(padChar);
  }
  return padded.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note that as of Java 1.5 it's worth using StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.

Answer (score 22):

Besides Apache Commons, also see `String.format` which should be able to take care of simple padding (e.g. with spaces).

Answer (score 20):

Since Java 11, String.repeat(int) can be used to left/right pad a given string.

```
System.out.println("*".repeat(5)+"apple");
System.out.println("apple"+"*".repeat(5));
```

Output:

```
*****apple
apple*****
```

Comment: for padding the number is dependent on the string length. what happen if you don't need padding (negative number)?

Comment: @Boaz I [generalized it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72236825/6243352) so that if the input string happens to be larger than the desired pad size, nothing happens.

Answer (score 16):

```
public static String LPad(String str, Integer length, char car) {
  return (str + String.format("%" + length + "s", "").replace(" ", String.valueOf(car))).substring(0, length);
}

public static String RPad(String str, Integer length, char car) {
  return (String.format("%" + length + "s", "").replace(" ", String.valueOf(car)) + str).substring(str.length(), length + str.length());
}

LPad("Hi", 10, 'R') //gives "RRRRRRRRHi"
RPad("Hi", 10, 'R') //gives "HiRRRRRRRR"
RPad("Hi", 10, ' ') //gives "Hi        "
RPad("Hi", 1, ' ')  //gives "H"
//etc...
```

Comment: Pay attention: you inverted functions names; if you run it you'll see.

Comment: plus if the original str contains spaces then this doesn't work

Comment: @StevenShaw If I'm not mistaken, the replace does not target the original `str`, so this is correct.

Comment: By convention you should not use a capital letter for function names.

Comment: Is there a missing conditional on returning the string as is when `(length - str.length())` is `0`? The formatter throws a `FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException` when `%0s` is the format string.

Answer (score 9):

Found this on [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples)

Pad with zeros:

```
String.format("|%020d|", 93); // prints: |00000000000000000093|
```

Comment: This should be the answer, simple and concise, no need to install external libraries.

Comment: Works with numeric values, but not for String values: ie, for "A83" it will not work. The 0 after the percent will rase an exception.

Answer (score 7):

i know this thread is kind of old and the original question was for an easy solution but if it's supposed to be really fast, you should use a char array.

```
public static String pad(String str, int size, char padChar)
{
    if (str.length() < size)
    {
        char[] temp = new char[size];
        int i = 0;

        while (i < str.length())
        {
            temp[i] = str.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }

        while (i < size)
        {
            temp[i] = padChar;
            i++;
        }

        str = new String(temp);
    }

    return str;
}
```

the formatter solution is not optimal. just building the format string creates 2 new strings.

apache's solution can be improved by initializing the sb with the target size so replacing below

```
StringBuffer padded = new StringBuffer(str);
```

with

```
StringBuffer padded = new StringBuffer(pad); 
padded.append(value);
```

would prevent the sb's internal buffer from growing.

Comment: If the `StringBuffer` can't be accessed by multiple threads at once (which in this case is true), you should use a `StringBuilder` (in JDK1.5+) to avoid the overhead of synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

This took me a little while to figure out.
The real key is to read that Formatter documentation.

```
// Get your data from wherever.
final byte[] data = getData();
// Get the digest engine.
final MessageDigest md5= MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
// Send your data through it.
md5.update(data);
// Parse the data as a positive BigInteger.
final BigInteger digest = new BigInteger(1,md5.digest());
// Pad the digest with blanks, 32 wide.
String hex = String.format(
    // See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html
    // Format: %[argument_index$][flags][width]conversion
    // Conversion: 'x', 'X'  integral    The result is formatted as a hexadecimal integer
    "%1$32x",
    digest
);
// Replace the blank padding with 0s.
hex = hex.replace(" ","0");
System.out.println(hex);
```

Comment: Why make the end so complicated? You could have just done String hex = String.format("%032x", digest); and had the exact same results, just without a needless replace() and having to use the $ to access specific variables (there's only one, after all.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare fair point. Someone originally asked for padding hex values in another question, I saw that I had a link to the formatter documentation. It's complicated for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to pad to the right:

```
// put the number of spaces, or any character you like, in your paddedString

String paddedString = "--------------------";

String myStringToBePadded = "I like donuts";

myStringToBePadded = myStringToBePadded + paddedString.substring(myStringToBePadded.length());

//result:
myStringToBePadded = "I like donuts-------";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the per-call overhead by retaining the padding data, rather than rebuilding it every time:

```
public class RightPadder {

    private int length;
    private String padding;

    public RightPadder(int length, String pad) {
        this.length = length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pad);
        while (sb.length() < length) {
            sb.append(sb);
        }
        padding = sb.toString();
   }

    public String pad(String s) {
        return (s.length() < length ? s + padding : s).substring(0, length);
    }

}
```

As an alternative, you can make the result length a parameter to the `pad(...)` method. In that case do the adjustment of the hidden padding in that method instead of in the constructor.

(Hint: For extra credit, make it thread-safe! ;-)

Comment: That is thread safe, except for unsafe publication (make your fields final, as a matter of course). I think performance could be improved by doing a substring before the + which should be replaced by concat (strangely enough).

Answer (score 3):

[@ck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4043913/2133216)'s and [@Marlon Tarak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7179819/2133216)'s answers are the only ones to use a `char[]`, which for applications that have several calls to padding methods per second is the best approach.  However, they don't take advantage of any array manipulation optimizations and are a little overwritten for my taste; this can be done with *no loops at all*.

```
public static String pad(String source, char fill, int length, boolean right){
    if(source.length() > length) return source;
    char[] out = new char[length];
    if(right){
        System.arraycopy(source.toCharArray(), 0, out, 0, source.length());
        Arrays.fill(out, source.length(), length, fill);
    }else{
        int sourceOffset = length - source.length();
        System.arraycopy(source.toCharArray(), 0, out, sourceOffset, source.length());
        Arrays.fill(out, 0, sourceOffset, fill);
    }
    return new String(out);
}
```

Simple test method:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    System.out.println("012345678901234567890123456789");
    System.out.println(pad("cats", ' ', 30, true));
    System.out.println(pad("cats", ' ', 30, false));
    System.out.println(pad("cats", ' ', 20, false));
    System.out.println(pad("cats", '$', 30, true));
    System.out.println(pad("too long for your own good, buddy", '#', 30, true));
}
```

Outputs:

```
012345678901234567890123456789
cats                          
                          cats
                cats
cats$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
too long for your own good, buddy
```

Comment: You can use [`getChars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars-int-int-char:A-int-) to let the `String` copy its contents directly into the `out` array, instead of calling `source.toCharArray()`, followed by `System.arraycopy`. I’d even consider simplifying the implementation to `char[] out = new char[length]; Arrays.fill(out, 0, length, fill); source.getChars(0, source.length(), out, right? 0: length - source.length()); return new String(out);`; while this looks like `fill` would do more work, it actually allows the JVM to eliminate the default zero-filling.

Answer (score 3):

All **string** operation usually needs to be **very efficient** - especially if you are working with big sets of data. I wanted something that's fast and flexible, similar to what you will get in plsql pad command. Also, I don't want to include a huge lib for just one small thing. With these considerations none of these solutions were satisfactory. This is the solutions I came up with, that had the best bench-marking results, if anybody can improve on it, please add your comment.

```
public static char[] lpad(char[] pStringChar, int pTotalLength, char pPad) {
    if (pStringChar.length < pTotalLength) {
        char[] retChar = new char[pTotalLength];
        int padIdx = pTotalLength - pStringChar.length;
        Arrays.fill(retChar, 0, padIdx, pPad);
        System.arraycopy(pStringChar, 0, retChar, padIdx, pStringChar.length);
        return retChar;
    } else {
        return pStringChar;
    }
}
```

- note it is called with String.toCharArray() and the result can be converted to String with new String((char[])result). The reason for this is, if you applying multiple operations you can do them all on char[] and not keep on converting between formats - behind the scenes, String is stored as char[]. If these operations were included in the String class itself, it would have been twice as efficient - speed and memory wise.

Comment: This indeed looks like the most efficient way

Comment: public static String lpad(String pString, int pTotalLength, char pPad) { return new String(lpad(pString.toCharArray(), pTotalLength, pPad)); }

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Formatter` will do left and right padding. No need for odd third party dependencies (would you want to add them for something so trivial).

[I've left out the details and made this post 'community wiki' as it is not something I have a need for.]

Comment: I disagree. In any larger Java project you will typically do such a lot of String manipulation, that the increased readability and avoidance of errors is well worth using Apache Commons Lang. You all know code like someString.subString(someString.indexOf(startCharacter), someString.lastIndexOf(endCharacter)), which can easily be avoided with StringUtils.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the built in StringBuilder append() and insert() methods,
for padding of variable string lengths:

```
AbstractStringBuilder append(CharSequence s, int start, int end) ;
```

For Example:

```
private static final String  MAX_STRING = "                    "; //20 spaces

    Set<StringBuilder> set= new HashSet<StringBuilder>();
    set.add(new StringBuilder("12345678"));
    set.add(new StringBuilder("123456789"));
    set.add(new StringBuilder("1234567811"));
    set.add(new StringBuilder("12345678123"));
    set.add(new StringBuilder("1234567812234"));
    set.add(new StringBuilder("1234567812222"));
    set.add(new StringBuilder("12345678122334"));

    for(StringBuilder padMe: set)
        padMe.append(MAX_STRING, padMe.length(), MAX_STRING.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
"".format("%1$-" + 9 + "s", "XXX").replaceAll(" ", "0")
```

It will fill your String XXX up to 9 Chars with a whitespace. After that all Whitespaces will be replaced with a 0. You can change the whitespace and the 0 to whatever you want...

Comment: You should invoke the `static` method as `String.format(…)` instead of abusing an empty string. Saving four characters in source code surely isn’t worth the loss of readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String padLeft(String in, int size, char padChar) {                
    if (in.length() <= size) {
        char[] temp = new char[size];
        /* Llenado Array con el padChar*/
        for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
            temp[i]= padChar;
        }
        int posIniTemp = size-in.length();
        for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
            temp[posIniTemp]=in.charAt(i);
            posIniTemp++;
        }            
        return new String(temp);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people have some very interesting techniques but I like to keep it simple so I go with this :

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n, char padding){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s.length() + n);
    builder.append(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        builder.append(padding);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static String padLeft(String s, int n,  char padding) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s.length() + n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        builder.append(Character.toString(padding));
    }
    return builder.append(s).toString();
}

public static String pad(String s, int n, char padding){
    StringBuilder pad = new StringBuilder(s.length() + n * 2);
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        pad.append(padding);
    }
    return value.append(pad).append(s).append(pad).toString();
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient, you should use a StringBuilder

Comment: Since you already know the length, you should tell the StringBuilder to allocate that much space when you instantiate it.

Comment: @Ariel interesting that you mention that because I was just talking to someone else about that today lol.

Comment: This is not padding but simple concatenation. You can just use .repeat() or any of the String.format thingies. The whole idea of a pad function is that you give it variable length input and it will return a fixed length output.

Comment: @JpLorandi you can accomplish this with `padLeft(text, desiredLength - text.length(), ' ')`

Answer (score 2):

Let's me leave an answer for some cases that you need to give left/right padding (or prefix/suffix string or spaces) before you concatenate to another string and you don't want to test length or any if condition.

The same to the selected answer, I would prefer the `StringUtils` of Apache Commons but using this way:

```
StringUtils.defaultString(StringUtils.leftPad(myString, 1))
```

Explain:

- `myString`: the string I input, can be null
- `StringUtils.leftPad(myString, 1)`: if string is null, this statement would return null too
- then use `defaultString` to give empty string to prevent concatenate null

Answer (score 2):

Java oneliners, no fancy library.

```
// 6 characters padding example
String pad = "******";
// testcases for 0, 4, 8 characters
String input = "" | "abcd" | "abcdefgh"
```

Pad Left, don't limit

```
result = pad.substring(Math.min(input.length(),pad.length())) + input;
results: "******" | "**abcd" | "abcdefgh"
```

Pad Right, don't limit

```
result = input + pad.substring(Math.min(input.length(),pad.length()));
results: "******" | "abcd**" | "abcdefgh"
```

Pad Left, limit to pad length

```
result = (pad + input).substring(input.length(), input.length() + pad.length());
results: "******" | "**abcd" | "cdefgh"
```

Pad Right, limit to pad length

```
result = (input + pad).substring(0, pad.length());
results: "******" | "abcd**" | "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function.

```
private String leftPadding(String word, int length, char ch) {
   return (length > word.length()) ? leftPadding(ch + word, length, ch) : word;
}
```

how to use?

```
leftPadding(month, 2, '0');
```

output:
01 02 03 04 .. 11 12

Comment: Using recursion means you're open to stack overflows, and it tends to be inefficient (repeated `ch + word` plus function call overhead).

Answer (score 2):

This is an **efficient** utility class for **left pad**, **right pad**, **center pad** and **zero fill** of strings in Java.

```java
package com.example;

/**
 * Utility class for left pad, right pad, center pad and zero fill.
 */
public final class StringPadding {

    public static String left(String string, int length, char fill) {

        if (string.length() < length) {

            char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
            char[] output = new char[length];

            int delta = length - chars.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (i < delta) {
                    output[i] = fill;
                } else {
                    output[i] = chars[i - delta];
                }
            }

            return new String(output);
        }

        return string;
    }

    public static String right(String string, int length, char fill) {

        if (string.length() < length) {

            char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
            char[] output = new char[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (i < chars.length) {
                    output[i] = chars[i];
                } else {
                    output[i] = fill;
                }
            }

            return new String(output);
        }

        return string;
    }

    public static String center(String string, int length, char fill) {

        if (string.length() < length) {

            char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

            int delta = length - chars.length;
            int a = (delta % 2 == 0) ? delta / 2 : delta / 2 + 1;
            int b = a + chars.length;

            char[] output = new char[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (i < a) {
                    output[i] = fill;
                } else if (i < b) {
                    output[i] = chars[i - a];
                } else {
                    output[i] = fill;
                }
            }

            return new String(output);
        }

        return string;
    }

    public static String zerofill(String string, int length) {
        return left(string, length, '0');
    }

    private StringPadding() {
    }

    /**
     * For tests!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "123";
        char blank = ' ';

        System.out.println("left pad:    [" + StringPadding.left(string, 10, blank) + "]");
        System.out.println("right pad:   [" + StringPadding.right(string, 10, blank) + "]");
        System.out.println("center pad:  [" + StringPadding.center(string, 10, blank) + "]");
        System.out.println("zero fill:   [" + StringPadding.zerofill(string, 10) + "]");
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
left pad:    [       123]
right pad:   [123       ]
center pad:  [    123   ]
zero fill:   [0000000123]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a parallel version for those of you that have very long Strings :-)

```
int width = 100;
String s = "129018";

CharSequence padded = IntStream.range(0,width)
            .parallel()
            .map(i->i-(width-s.length()))
            .map(i->i<0 ? '0' :s.charAt(i))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb,c)-> sb.append((char)c), (sb1,sb2)->sb1.append(sb2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing [Eko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459347/6243352) (Java 11+) a bit:

```java
public class StringUtils {
    public static String padLeft(String s, char fill, int padSize) {
        if (padSize < 0) {
            var err = "padSize must be >= 0 (was " + padSize + ")";
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(err);
        }

        int repeats = Math.max(0, padSize - s.length());
        return Character.toString(fill).repeat(repeats) + s;
    }

    public static String padRight(String s, char fill, int padSize) {
        if (padSize < 0) {
            var err = "padSize must be >= 0 (was " + padSize + ")";
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(err);
        }

        int repeats = Math.max(0, padSize - s.length());
        return s + Character.toString(fill).repeat(repeats);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(padLeft("", 'x', 5)); // => xxxxx
        System.out.println(padLeft("1", 'x', 5)); // => xxxx1
        System.out.println(padLeft("12", 'x', 5)); // => xxx12
        System.out.println(padLeft("123", 'x', 5)); // => xx123
        System.out.println(padLeft("1234", 'x', 5)); // => x1234
        System.out.println(padLeft("12345", 'x', 5)); // => 12345
        System.out.println(padLeft("123456", 'x', 5)); // => 123456

        System.out.println(padRight("", 'x', 5)); // => xxxxx
        System.out.println(padRight("1", 'x', 5)); // => 1xxxx
        System.out.println(padRight("12", 'x', 5)); // => 12xxx
        System.out.println(padRight("123", 'x', 5)); // => 123xx
        System.out.println(padRight("1234", 'x', 5)); // => 1234x
        System.out.println(padRight("12345", 'x', 5)); // => 12345
        System.out.println(padRight("123456", 'x', 5)); // => 123456

        System.out.println(padRight("1", 'x', -1)); // => throws
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was looking for something that would pad around and then I decided to code it myself. It's fairly clean and you can easily derive padLeft and padRight from this

```
    /**
     * Pads around a string, both left and right using pad as the template, aligning to the right or left as indicated.
     * @param a the string to pad on both left and right
     * @param pad the template to pad with, it can be of any size
     * @param width the fixed width to output
     * @param alignRight if true, when the input string is of odd length, adds an extra pad char to the left, so values are right aligned
     *                   otherwise add an extra pad char to the right. When the input is of even length no extra chars will be inserted
     * @return the input param a padded around.
     */
    public static String padAround(String a, String pad, int width, boolean alignRight) {
        if (pad.length() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pad cannot be an empty string!");
        int delta = width - a.length();
        if (delta < 1)
            return a;
        int half = delta / 2;
        int remainder = delta % 2;
        String padding = pad.repeat(((half+remainder)/pad.length()+1)); // repeating the padding to occupy all possible space
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(width);
//        sb.append( padding.substring(0,half + (alignRight ? 0 : remainder)));
        sb.append(padding, 0, half + (alignRight ? 0 : remainder));
        sb.append(a);
//        sb.append( padding.substring(0,half + (alignRight ? remainder : 0)));
        sb.append(padding, 0, half + (alignRight ? remainder : 0));

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

While it should be fairly fast it could prolly benefit from using a few finals here and there.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own function for this is probably simpler than other answers.

```
private static String padRight(String str, String padChar, int n) {

    String paddedString = str;

    while (paddedString.length() < n) {

        paddedString = padChar + str;

    }

    return paddedString;

}

private static String padLeft(String str, String padChar, int n) {

    String paddedString = str;

    while (paddedString.length() < n) {

        paddedString += padChar;

    }

    return paddedString;

}
```

Comment: This is *very* inefficient!

Comment: but it is very straightforward

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty test you can use this:

```
String myString = "hello";
for(;myString.length() < 32; hello = "0" + hello); //pad left
for(;myString.length() < 32; hello += "0"); //pad rigth
```

I found it usefull printing a long value in a binary representation:

```
String wildCardBinaryString = Long.toBinaryString(255);
for(;wildCardBinaryString.length() < 32; wildCardBinaryString = "0" + wildCardBinaryString);
System.out.println(String.format("|%s|", Long.toBinaryString(wildcard)));
```

It prints:

```
|00000000000000000000000011111111|
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow padding of any string instead of limiting you to numbers, and code is clean and concise:

```
private static String leftPad(int length, char padCharacter, Object object) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String string = object == null ? "" : object.toString();
    int remaining = Math.max(0, length - string.length());
    IntStream.range(0, remaining).forEach(i -> builder.append(padCharacter));
    return builder.append(string).toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution would be:

```
package nl;
public class Padder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123" ;
        System.out.println("#"+("     " + s).substring(s.length())+"#");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

s = String to pad 
n = Desired length 
c = Char to pad

```
private String padStart( String s, int n, char c ){
    if( n <= 0 ) return s;
    else return String.format("%" + n + "s", s).replace(' ', c);
}
```

Comment: This breaks completely on any string containing spaces.