# Formatting my String

Tags: java, string-formatting

I need to write currency values like $35.40 (thirty five dollars and forty cents)
and after that, i want to write some `"****"`

so at the end it will be: 
`thirty five dollars and forty cents*********`
in a maximun of 100 characters

I've asked a question about something very likely but I couldn't understand the main command.

```
String format = String.format("%%-%ds", 100);
String valorPorExtenso = String.format(format, new Extenso(tituloTO.getValor()).toString());
```

What do I need to change on format to put `***` at the end of my sentence?
The way it is now it puts spaces.

Comment: This is a more specific duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/padding-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formatting will give you 100 characters including your string

```
String.format("%-100s", "thirty five dollars and forty cents.").replaceAll("  ", "**");
```

**UPDATE :**

```
String.format("%-100s", "thirty five dollars and forty cents.").replaceAll("  ", "**").replace("* ", "**");
```

Comment: beware, this will not work correctly if you have an uneven number of spaces at the end of the string.

Comment: the resulting string will have a length of 100 but if there is an uneven number of spaces, the last char will be a space

Comment: @morja and Redlab - I thing pringlesinn was not keen to get exact 100 characters trimming trailing space. But still if you want it please check and comment on the update.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
String line = "thirty five dollars and forty cents";
StringBuilder lineBuffer = new StringBuilder(line);
for(int i=0; i < 100 - line.length(); i++){
    lineBuffer.append("*");
}
line = lineBuffer.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at commons-lang http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html

I'm under the impression that you want to pad this out to 100 characters.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29

The other option is to create a base string of 100 '*' characters.

Create a string builder and do the following:

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(new Extenso(tituloTO.getValor()).toString());
sb.append(STARS_STR);
String val= sb.substring(0, 100);
```

That should get out the value formatted out.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't pad with anything other than spaces using String.format. Either use [apache StringUtils](http://www.jdocs.com/lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) or write a snippet of code to do it yourself, there is an answer here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0448.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't with String.format(), there are however utils to do it in apache's StringUtils. Or just write little method that append the * for your specified length.