# Adding whitespace in Java

Tags: java, whitespace, space, trim, spaces

There is a class `trim()` to remove white spaces, how about adding/padding?

Note: `" "` is not the solution.

Comment: Add some examples of "before" and "after".

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think you are talking about padding strings with spaces.

One way to do this is with string [format codes.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail)

For example, if you want to pad a string to a certain length with spaces, use something like this:

```
String padded = String.format("%-20s", str);
```

In a formatter, `%` introduces a format sequence. The `-` means that the string will be left-justified (spaces will be added at the end of the string). The `20` means the resulting string will be 20 characters long. The `s` is the character string format code, and ends the format sequence.

Comment: The length of the character and space is different, How can I ensure same length?

Comment: @surendrapanday I’m sorry but I don’t understand your question. Can you explain more? Maybe an example?

Comment: This solution produces correct output in the console, but when using the same string in BufferedImage to create Image from the string, this produce output something.
aaa   : bbb
mmm  : ccc

Comment: @surendrapanday That will depend very much on the `Graphics` calls you make to render the buffered image. To render an image of formatted text, I would probably explore using Swing components with a layout to do the painting. That's outside the scope of this question and answer, but if you ask a new question, you could link it here.

Comment: If I use swing component then will there be any behavior change on the different platform  (like Andriod, Windows, Mac, etc)

Comment: Great stuff, works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

Use the StringUtils class, it also includes null check

```
StringUtils.leftPad(String str, int size)
StringUtils.rightPad(String str, int size)
```

Comment: Thank Yaniv Levi. Your answer very straightforward. I want to explain more for others.
- size: is the length of characters include str and spaces (left or right).

Answer (score 2):

There's a few approaches for this:

1. Create a char array then use Arrays.fill, and finally convert to a String
2. Iterate through a loop adding a space each time
3. [Use String.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/padding-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "text";
text += new String(" ");
```

Comment: If you had read the entire question, you would have seen: `Note: " " is not the solution.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Instance of the EditText available at the point in your code where you want add whitespace, then this code below will work. There may be some things to consider, for example the code below may trigger any TextWatcher you have set to this EditText, idk for sure, just saying, but this will work when trying to append blank space like this: " ", hasn't worked.

```
messageInputBox.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can be done with the help of apache StringUtils class is space.

```
StringUtils.SPACE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the print format as well to add whitespace. For example, you can give length to a string like this example.
System.out.printf("%-15s",str);

Comment: Similar answer is already provided in other answer.