# Java string align to right

Tags: java, formatter

I have an array of these numbers

```
61672
8414449
264957
```

I use a `DecimalFormat` object like this

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,### bytes");
```

to get these results

```
61,672 bytes
8,414,449 bytes
264,957 bytes
```

but I need the results to be aligned to right like the following

```
   61,672 bytes
8,414,449 bytes
  264,957 bytes
```

Your help is already appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/padding-strings-in-java

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can wrap it into a `String.format` call like this:

```
String.format("%15s", formatter.format(i))
```

Comment: Straight forward. Thanks!

Comment: @David The OP defined that object.