# Java text file rows alignment

Tags: java

I have text file having multiple rows of data.here I want to align all the rows properly.suppose take below scenario.

```
John.      12345
Steve.         32456
Mike.               62345
```

Based on above data,32456 and 62345 should align with 12345 properly.I want to do this with java.any clues on this.

Thanks
Chaitu

Comment: Do you produce the text file yourself or it exists already and you just want to format it?

Comment: Here I am trying to read first row reversely and trying to find the position of last row.based on that planning to set the second,third

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080390/java-string-align-to-right).

Comment: Kris:I am getting that data from db and writing into the text file, before I do this. I have to format it properly

Comment: Adarshr: I don't know before whether I can do left or right pad initially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF your output is going to be displayed in fixed-width fonts, then you can use the java.util.Formatter class and give each output string a width to line them up.  String.format uses the Formatter format syntax:

```
for (ScoreObject score : scoreList)
{
  String.format("%20s %15s", score.getName(), score.getScore());
}
```

But you don't say where your output is going, or whether you are using a fixed-width font, etc., so I can only hope this is what you're asking.

Comment: If there are variable width fonts about but you can set tab widths, just writing everything out with tabs as separators can be good enough.