# Java: How to right justify text, with Variable

Tags: java, string, text, format

I am trying to align some text on the right side like so:

```
String text = "whatever";
System.out.printf("%4s", text);
```

Except instead of the number 4 in the format scheme I want to use an integer variable, but I cannot find out how to do that. Please help.

What I tried:

```
int spaceCount = 4;
String text = "whatever";
System.out.printf("%{spaceCount}s", text);
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080390/java-string-align-to-right

Answer (score 3):

Java ain't groovy; you have to build up the format old school:

```
System.out.printf("%" + spaceCount + "s", text);
```

If you wanted to avoid coding String concatenation, you could format the format:

```
System.out.printf(String.format("%%%ds", spaceCount), text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) document points out:

> A convenience method to write a formatted string to this output stream using the **specified format string** and arguments.

So it would be easy to achieve the **parameterized** alignment as:

```
System.out.printf("%" + spaceCount + "s", "Hello");
```

Also it mentions:

> An invocation of this method of the form out.printf(format, args) behaves in exactly the **same** way as the invocation: `out.format(format, args)`

So you can also achieve it as:

```
System.out.format("%" + spaceCount + "s", "Hello");
```