# How to left pad integers with a formatter with dots?

Tags: java, formatter

I know we can left-pad integers with a formatter like this:

```
String.format("%7d", 234);   // "    234"
String.format("%07d", 234);  // "0000234"
String.format("%015d", 234); // "0000000000000234"
```

But, how to replace the zeros by dots (like a plain text content index)?

```
String.format("%.13d", 234); // doesn't work
```

I want to produce this:

```
..........234
```

I know I can use a loop to add the dots, but I want to know if there is a way to do this with a formatter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/padding-strings-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no such `.` padding build in, but you can pad with spaces and then replace them.

```
 String.format("%15d", 234).replaceAll(' ', '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do with with the formatter alone, but

```
String.format("%015d", 234).replaceFirst("0*","\.");
```

should do just fine.

(Naturally, you have to then *do* something with the string -- this one produces a String object which then disappears, since this doesn't assign to anything.)

Update

Damn, forgot the repeat `*` in the regex.

Comment: @Martijn, you'll probably find in the future that saying what error you think you've found will serve you well.

Comment: The errors, I found without compiling are: 1) All the zeros will be replaced by one single dot. 2) `"\."` is an non-existing escape character. So, if you meant `\\.`, it won't be replaced by a dot but with literally `\.`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the Apache Commons Lang lib.
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29

grundprinzip already pointed that out...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually. It is not beautiful but it works.

```
String str = Integer.toString( 234 );
str = "...............".substring( 0, Math.max( 0, 15 - str.length() ) ) + str;
```