# velocity template format

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

I Have velocity template like this one :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| $totalPel  Pelanggan                                      |    $totalBk |   $totalAdm |   $totalTag | $totalTotal |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

When i put $totalPel -> 100, the result is :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 100  Pelanggan                                      |    $totalBk |   $totalAdm |   $totalTag | $totalTotal |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Actually I want to get the result like this :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 100        Pelanggan                                      |    $totalBk |   $totalAdm |   $totalTag | $totalTotal |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Anyone can show me how to make it?

I use this java code :

```
Velocity.init();

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("totalPel", 100);

Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("LaporanTagihan.txt");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

template.merge(context, writer);

System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: I can't really understand what you want here... what's the difference? just more space? That's usually controlled in the template.

Comment: yes, I just want to automatic add space for the result. It's is useful when I put a lot of parameter :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pad your strings before adding them to your template.  See [How can I pad a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java) for advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can either transform the value into a String and pad it, or you can simply add more space in your template, I believe velocity maintains whitespace that you define.