# how to pad space within a string in java?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, padding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pad a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java)

I have a stuation in which my method1() return the string of various size and I want to display the string in a fix space (say length 50 character) I can use String.substring() if the length is greater than 50 character but not sure what to do if the string length is less than 50 character , how can I achieve that ?

```
for example my method1() return (in different call) :
John
Michael
J
Ab

While method2() return :
first
Second
Third
```

and I want to print the result like

```
John                 First
Michael              Second
J                    Third
Ab                   Forth
```

I don't want to use any other character except space.

Comment: I have tried String.format() but that did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String toFixedLength(String str, int sz) {      
  String ret;
  int len = str.length();

  if (len == sz) {
    ret = str;
  } else if (len > sz) {
    ret = str.substring(0, sz);
  } else { // len < sz
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

    char[] ch = new char[sz - len];
    Arrays.fill(ch, ' ');
    sb.append(ch);
    ret = sb.toString();
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: not working in the following scenario

Answer (score 0):

Just check the string's `length()` and add the required number of spaces (say, in a cycle)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string with a length of less than fifty characters and you want to pad it out, you could just do:

```
int temp = yourstring.length

for(int i = 0; i < (50-temp); i++){
  yourstring = yourstring + " ";
}
```

I'm pretty sure that'd work, if yourstring is the string you're trying to pad and you haven't used i as an integer previously in your code. This way you only have to use space.