# Variable widths in Java's String.format method

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I'm working on a project in which I need to display textual trees. I'm trying to use Java's String.format method to simplify the formatting process, but I ran into trouble when trying to apply variable widths.

Current I have a variable (an int) which is called depth.

I try to do the following:

```
String.format("%"+depth+"s"," ") + getOriginalText() + "\n";
```

However I get the following error.

```
java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = 0
```

Any suggestions on how to do this, or should I just settle for loops?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you actually asking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Comment: Can you post the full code, I'm trying to understand what are you doing.

Comment: I wondered this also because I knew that C/C++ had a  `*` modifier: `The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.`, i.e. I was searching for something like `String.format( "%*i", pad_width, number )`. But the given answer makes sense, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works:

```
int depth = 5;
String str= "Hello"+ String.format("%"+depth+"s"," ") + "world" + "\n";
System.out.println(str);
```

It prints 5 while spaces in between.

> Hello     World.

Please check you code and make sure that `depth` is assigned with a valid `int` value. Most likely that (invalid value in `depth`) is the problem.

Comment: That makes sense. I had a massive lapse in thought I guess. I forgot that I pass zero for depth for the first call, and "%0s" is an error.

Comment: @PhillipHuff: Good to know. If you feel, this is helpful then don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following using "System.out.printf" command:

```
int depth = 10;

System.out.printf("%s" + "%" +depth + "s", "Hello","World" );
```

> Hello    World