# How do I format a list of Strings in Java from a TreeMap to print this way?

Tags: java, string, format, treemap, spacing

I'm making a list of strings in a TreeMap to keep track of grades for a bunch of students. Right now my program is printing the list of strings like this:

```
Jimmy: C+
Tim: A
Samantha: B-
Mike: A-
```

When I want it to print out like this:

```
Jimmy:    C+
Tim:      A
Samantha: B-
Mike:     A-
```

How do I get the names and grades to be spaced like this? Here's the section of my code that prints out everything:

```
//Print all students with their grades
case "P": System.out.println();
          for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : grades.entrySet())
          {
             System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":  " + entry.getValue());
          }
          System.out.println();
          break;
```

Comment: Use `\t` in System.out.println(..) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably using a tab character instead of spaces in your print statement.

```
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":\t" + entry.getValue());
```

Another way to do it is using the String [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method to right-pad the student's name with spaces.  The following code will print a student's name in a column 10 characters wide.  This will be more reliable if you know the maximum length of names before printing the report (which you should be able to find easily).

```
String name = "Tim:";
String student = String.format("%1$-10s", name);
System.out.println(student + "A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at option of using System.out.format with different format options like right justifying out etc. Just google this. Here is one [link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) you an look at

Answer (score 0):

You want to left-pad the strings.
Check out this answer: [How can I pad a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java)

You also might want a function to calculate the maximum length of all the names you're trying to output. Something like.

```
private int maxLength(Collection<String> names) {
        int max = 0;
        for (String s : names) {
            if (s.length() > max) {
                max = s.length();
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Then, use it like this:  maxLength(grades.keySet());

Answer (score 0):

Input this to the `System.out.println()` in your loop:

```
String.format("%-10s %s", entry.getKey()+":", entry.getValue());
```