# Write string to a specific position in file

Tags: java, io, bufferedwriter

I am using `BufferedWriter` to write strings to a file like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       String myname = "JOHN DOE MAXWELL";
       String myotherName = "MELCHIZEDEK NEBUCHARDINEZZAR";
       String mylocation = "SOUTH EAST";
       String myotherlocation = "SOUTH WEST";
       File f = new File("MyFile.txt");
       BufferedWriter bw  = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
       bw.write(myname + "                       " + mylocation);
       bw.newLine();
       bw.write(myothername + "                  " + myotherlocation);
       bw.close();
    }
}
```

I need to write `mylocation` such that whatever the length of the string `myname`, the beginning position of `mylocation` will not be affected. Please assist.

My Outputshould be:

```
JOHN DOE MAXWELL          SOUTH EAST
MELCHIZEDEK NEBUCHARDI    SOUTH WEST
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of what you'd like the resulting file to look like. Perhaps two examples, with different length `myname`s?

Comment: Insertion at a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
bw.write(String.format("%-20s%s%n", myName, myLocation));
```

You can use PrintWriter to use printf() which does both.

e.g. Using PrintWriter

```
pw.printf("%-" + myNameWidth + "s%s%n", myName, myLocation);
```

Comment: Good answer. One could also produce a generic pad-to-length method, using the same technique. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/391978/474189 for examples.

Comment: Out of curiousity what if I wanted three Strings like `bw.write(String.format("%-20s%s%n", myName, myLocation, MyotherString));`

Comment: You need another `%-20s` or `%-32s` or whatever you desired width is. Note the `-` assumes you want left justified.  Without it the string is right justified like numbers are.

Comment: If I do `%-20s` the Third String will start right after the second without the space, if I do `%20s` if the two third strings are not of equal lentgth the longer will start first, WHat does s represent?

Comment: The order doesn't change, it will always be the order you give.  The number is the width of each field, not to offset from the start.

Comment: Using "%20s%-20s" can result in the two strings running into each other so you can do "%20s %-20s" to ensure there is always one space between them.

Comment: Oh ok Thank you , now I got it completely.

Answer (score 1):

> such that whatever the length of the string myname, the beginning
>   position of mylocation will not be affected

The only case i can think of is when each one is in a new line.

You must specify the maximum tolerted length after which this order is no longer guaranteed, the formating actually should occur on reading the file, at that point you can determine the longest variable of myname and format your output according to it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
bw.write(myname + "                             ".substring(0, 30) + " " + mylocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padEnd%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29):

```
Strings.padEnd("JOHN DOE MAXWELL", 26, ' ').length()
```

String will be always 26 characters length.