# How to Print a specific amount of spaces per line in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get a Java program to print a specific amount of spaces per line and then drop down to continue the list. I am finding all prime numbers in a user specified range and then printing out the number of primes in the range and the prime numbers themselves. Anytime the program finds a number that is not a prime number it should print a - . So far, I have:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNums {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    int startingVal;
    int endingVal;
    int index;
    int currNum = 2;
    boolean prime;
    int count=0;

    //***  Input  ***

    System.out.println("Enter the Starting Number of the Range: ");
    startingVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the Ending Value of the Range: ");
    endingVal = keyboard.nextInt();



    //*** Checks for Parameters  ***

    while(startingVal>1000||startingVal%10!=0){
        System.out.println("Starting Value was not evenly divisible by 10. Reenter Starting Value: ");
        startingVal= keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    while(startingVal>=endingVal||endingVal%10!=0||endingVal>1000){
        System.out.println("Ending Value was less than Starting Value or Did Not Follow Guideline. Reenter Ending Value: ");
        endingVal=keyboard.nextInt();
    }


    //***  Stores Checked Variables  ***

    int range = (endingVal);
    int[] primeArray = new int[10];

    //*** Checks for all Prime Numbers  ***

    for(index=startingVal; index<range; index++){

        if(index==1||index%2==0||index%3==0||index%4==0||index%5==0||index%6==0||index%7==0||index%8==0||index%9==0||index%10==0){
            System.out.print("-");
        }else{
            count++;
            System.out.print(index);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + count + " Prime Numbers in this range.");
}


}
```

So far, this program finds all the prime numbers within the range and prints them out. However, I need the code to print out in sets of 10. Something like this:
Range here is: 70-200.

---

71  -  73  - - - -   - 79  - | 80

- - 83  - - - -   - 89  - | 90
- - - - - - 97  - -   - | 100

101 -  103 - - - 107 - 109 - | 110

- - 113 - - - -   - -   - | 120
- - - - - - 127 - -   - | 130

131 -  -   - - - 137 - 139 - | 140

- - - - - - - - 149 - | 150

151 -  -   - - - 157 - -   - | 160

- - 163  - - - 167 - -   - | 170
- - 173  - - - -   - 179 - | 180

181 - -    - - - -   - -   - | 190

191 - 193  - - - 197 - 199 - | 200

---

There are 27 prime numbers between 70 and 200

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Comment: Write a method that can return a `String` which will contain the specified number of spaces.  You will need a `while-loop` to achieve it...

Comment: @user2284528 did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subtracting the starting value with index you'll get the loop number, which will be the same as if you were using a counter. Once you know that, `%sizeOfSet == 0` will return true if the counter is divisible by `sizeOfSet` (the number of outputs per set, as you specified, 10).

```
int sizeOfSet = 10;
if ((index-startingVal) %sizeOfSet == 0){
//prints out an empty line
System.out.printf("%n");
}
```

This code should be included at the end of the for loop after the if-else statement.