# howto nicely format text on console when the output is longer than \t

Tags: java, formatting

How can I fix this formatting issue? I'm outputing text to my console and the \t is not aligned correctly (because the amount if too long). I can cheaply fix it with an 'if' statement that check the length but wonder if there's a better way to do this.

thanks

[image]

snap of code:

```
    //here comes the title/header (Dec-12.......Jan-13.......)

    for (int r=0; r<table.rowKeySet().size(); r++)
    {
        Map<Integer, SaleReportEntity> map = table.row(r);
        System.out.print(map.get(0).getSalePeriodStr()+"\t");

        for (int c=0; c<table.columnKeySet().size(); c++)
        {
            SaleReportEntity sre = map.get(c);
            System.out.print(sre.getTotalAmountStr()+"\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println(); //new line
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Comment: You *may* want to look at `DecimalFormat` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but I believe the printf(...) method allows you to control spacing and formatting. Very simple example:

```
System.out.printf("%7s%7s%7s%7s", "a", "b", "c", "d");
```