# Using \t to line up a file output

Tags: java, file-io, spacing

I am trying to format a file output so that everything is lined up nicely, and its almost working. I've used \t to try to give the output a uniform rigid look. It is almost there, but it isn't quite working for one (see below) I think it is because the team name is too short, but I'm not sure any suggestions?

My Code:

```
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Team newTeam = new Team(str);
            teamArray[counter] = newTeam;
            out.println(newTeam.getTeamName() + ": "+ "\t"  + newTeam.getBatAvgStr() + " " + newTeam.getSlugAvgStr());
```

my output:

## 2011 Regular Season

```
TEAM              BA   SA
Boston:         .280 .461
NY_Yankees:     .263 .444
Texas:  .283 .460
Detroit:        .277 .434
St.Louis:       .273 .425
Toronto:        .249 .413
Cincinnati:     .256 .408
Colorado:       .258 .410
Arizona:        .250 .413
Kansas_City:    .275 .415
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use smth like :

```
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
        Team newTeam = new Team(str);
        teamArray[counter] = newTeam;
        out.println(String.format("%1$-20s : %2$-5s %3$-5s",newTeam.getTeamName(), newTeam.getBatAvgStr(), newTeam.getSlugAvgStr()));
```

But I didn't test it, so I'm not really sure...

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring to the fact that "Texas" has too few letter to offset the first tab in line with the others. Assuming that you're using `PrintWriter`, you could use [printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) rather than `println` and use format specifiers to pad the `String` tokens:

```
out.printf("%14s:  %14s  %14s", 
             newTeam.getTeamName(), newTeam.getBatAvgStr(),  
                newTeam.getSlugAvgStr());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using String.Format();

Example:

```
>     public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
>          return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
>     }
>     
>     public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
>         return String.format("%1$" + n + "s", s);  
>     }
>     
>     ...
>     
>     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
>      System.out.println(padRight("Howto", 20) + "*");
>      System.out.println(padLeft("Howto", 20) + "*");
>     }

/*
  output :
     Howto               *
                    Howto*
*/
```

Was answered here: [**String Pad**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java)