# How to print a table using System.out.print?

Tags: java, formatting, console-application

I need help into formating the output of an Java application on which I work.

The output should look like this(evrey line bellow coresponding category):

```
---------------------------------------------------
|Account number| Savings Balance| Checking Balance|
---------------------------------------------------
|an integer    | a double       |         a double|
---------------------------------------------------
|............  | .........      |      ...........|
---------------------------------------------------
```

What I have done:

```
System.out.println("|--------------| ---------------| ----------------|");
             System.out.println("|Account number| Savings balance| Checking balance|");
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            {

            System.out.println("|"+a[i].getAccountNo()+"|"+a[i].getSavingBal()+"|"+a[i].getCheckingBal()+"|");
            System.out.println("|--------------| ---------------| ----------------|");

        }
            System.out.println("|--------------| ---------------| ----------------|");
```

Comment: try \t in your string to add a tab

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

u can use String.format() like

System.out.println(String.format("%03d %7s %7s %11s", val1, val2, val3, val4));