# Use variable in printf format specifier Java

Tags: java, format, printf

I am making a basic spreadsheet program, and by default I have the cell width set to 12 spaces. I am using printf to do this.

```
System.out.printf("%12s|", rowsAndColumns[i][j]);
```

How can I do something like.

```
System.out.printf("%cellWidths|", rowsAndColumns[i][j]);
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: See answers to [How can I pad a String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java).

Comment: @Nick are you creating a spreadsheet that writes to the standard output? I think you ought to be using a GUI for that, isn't it?

Comment: The spreadsheet isn't using a GUI, its using print statements to print the rows and columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you are looking for is possible.

But why don't you do it as follows -

```
System.out.printf("%" + cellWidths + "|", rowsAndColumns[i][j]);
```