# Utility class for always having a string with fixed length?

Tags: java, string

Probably there is already some kind of apache or guava utility class for my requirement:

I want to always create strings of the same length. The missing characters should be filled either left or right with a fixed character. Something like:

```
Utils.filledString(teststring, " ", 5); //would ensure the teststring is always 5 chars long, and if not append whitespace to the right
Utils.filledString(teststring, "x", -5); //same as above, but fill the 5 chars left with an x
```

You get the idea, and probably it's already there, but I'm missing the right keyword to find it.

Comment: String.format is your friend. No utility class needed.

Comment: Review the documentation of [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Comment: possibile duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [apache commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang) StringUtils:
 [StringUtils.rightPad(String str, int size, String padStr)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)
[StringUtils.leftPad(String str, int size, String padStr](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
StringUtils.rightPad("bat", 5, "")    = "bat  "
StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 5, "x")    = "xxbat"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is already a solution in guava project. [Google Guava String](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html).
It is called padEnd/padStart