# 16 bytes length becomes sometimes 15 bytes length

Tags: java, byte, tostring, biginteger

I'm using some code to generate a 16 bytes length String and
I noticed a ***strange*** behaviour while using my code which is:

```
public static String generateMyUniqueString() {
    return new BigInteger(64,oRandom).toString(16);
}
```

This is giving me a nice 16 characters length string 99% of the time.
But yes, **sometimes**, the generated string is 15 characters length and, for now, I did not find why.

Comment: I bet it happens 1/16 of the time. If the value is less than 2^56, then it will not require 16 digits.

Comment: From where are you getting `oRandom` from?

Comment: @Makoto oRandom comes from `private static SecureRandom oRandom = new SecureRandom();`

Comment: @RaymondChen
Ahhh! thanks a lot! I was thinking about something similar, I guess you're right!
Thanks for enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try

```
public static String generateMyUniqueString() {
    return String.format("%016x", new BigInteger(64, oRandom));
}
```

This will always be 16 digits long as it zero pads the start.

BTW: if you generate 4 billion of these ids there is a 50/50 changes two will be the same.

Have you considered using UUID (128 bit), or a durable counters instead?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and no I did not considered using UUID.

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads:

Generate a random secure 64-bit integer and convert it to a hexadecimal string.

When it's converted to a string, leading zeroes are omitted. If you are really lucky you could also get a result with 14 or less digits.

If you want to always have a 16-digit value, you need to add leading zeros manually.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185386/3264295 for an example how to pad a string