# How to append a blank character till specified length?

Tags: java, string

Consider a string which is needed to be inserted in some query or file where the length of string should be equal to 40. If length of string is less than 40, then it should append empty characters till length 40 is achieved, and then it needs to be inserted. How should I do this?

```
 void addstring(String str)
 {
      int len=str.length();
      PrintStream out=new PrintStream();
      if(len<=40)
      {
          out.print(str);
      }
      else
      {
          //make the string of length 40 by appending blank character and write to the file. 
      }
 }
```

Comment: make the string of length 40 or 14

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) as follows:

```
out.printf("%-40s", str);
```

For details on the format string, refer to *Format String Syntax* in the documentation of [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Note that if the string exceeds `40` characters, the string as a whole will be printed (without any padding spaces of course), so the `if` statement is redundant and can be dropped.

If you're using **Guava** you can use [`Strings.padEnd`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padEnd%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29).

If you're using **Apache Commons**, you can use [`StringUtils.repeat`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and construct the padding manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringUtils.repeat()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method if you are using Apache commons.

```
String extraStr = StringUtils.repeat(" ", 40-len);
```

And then append it to your string.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called 'padding', see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java) for more details.

Also, I would advise to check for a length *greater than or equal to* 40:

```
if (len >= 40)
{
    out.print(str);
}
else
{
    out.printf("%-40s", str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
if(str.length()<40) {
    out.printf("%-40s", str);
} else {
    out.printf("larger in size");
}
```