# Add variable amount of trailing zeros based on input integer

Tags: java, decimal, zero, digits, decimalformat

There are a lot of questions regarding rounding decimal to 2 decimals points after the comma, or adding leading zeros. I'm unable however, to find one which adds trailing zeros with a variable amount of zeros.

**What I want to achieve:**
With a positive integer ***n***, I want to have the decimal 1/***n*** with ***n*** amount of digits after the comma. So the first 10 would be:

```
1/1 = 1        ->   1.0
1/2 = 0.5      ->   0.50
1/3 = 1.333... ->   1.333
1/4 = 0.25     ->   0.2500
1/5 = 0.2      ->   0.20000
1/6 = 0.666... ->   0.666666
1/7 = 0.142... ->   0.1428571
1/8 = 0.125    ->   0.12500000
1/9 = 0.111... ->   0.111111111
1/10 = 0.1     ->   0.1000000000
```

Preferably I have the result as a String and use code which is as short as possible. So no for-loops, or all kind of Formatter settings. Preferably something like `String.format(..., n);` or some other short solution.

I did try `String.format("%f0", 1./n);` to see what it would output, but this only adds up until 7 digits (no idea how this is set up and if this is configurable). So for `String.format("%f0", 1./8);` the output is `0.1250000` missing the 8th zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String.format("%." + n + "f", (1.0/n));
```

Comment: Hmm.. for `n = 18` it results in `0.0555555555555555500` instead of `0.055555555555555555` :S

Comment: This is due to the fact a double has only 17 significant digits.

Comment: Yeah, came to the same conclusion closely after making the comment. I guess I should go look into `BigDecimals` and a similar format based on the one you've provided.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll have to use `BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(n), n, RoundingMode.CEILING).toString()` instead. Will keep your answer as accepted though, since it works as a charm up until 17 and is using a short `String.format` as I preferred for this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont get the "single" format to work, there is an easy workaround: create the desired output in two steps.

Example for your 1/8 case:

1. `value = "0.125";`
2. you want a total length of 10 ( 0 . and 8 digits!), so simply create a another string `padding = "00000";`

And return `value + padding`

The padding can be done easily using String.format(), too; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java) for various examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **NumberFormat** [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and set `setMaximumFractionDigits` and `setMinimumFractionDigits`

## Example

```
private static void resolveDecimalPlaces(int i) {
    final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(i);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(i);
    nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    System.out.println(nf.format(1.0 / i));
}
```