# Java - Loop through all inputs with input mask xxxxxxx where x = 0 or 1

Tags: java, string, loops, input

So I am trying to create an `AList` of `AClass(es)` with a `7-switch String` parameter where each character is either on [1] or off [0], E.g: `0011010`.

```
ArrayList<AClass> AList = new ArrayList<AClass>();    

public BClass() {
    // I believe there is 128 unique ways to arrange between 0000000 and 1111111
    for (int i = 0; i < ?; i++) {
        // I assume I would need to create the String some how here and use that.
        String str;
        AList.add(new AClass("0000000"));

        / * Each loop would create a new one, you get the idea.
        AList.add(new AClass("1000000"));
        AList.add(new AClass("1100000"));
        AList.add(new AClass("1110000"));
        ...
        ...
        AList.add(new AClass("1001010"));
        ...
        ...
        AList.add(new AClass("1111111"));
        */
    }
}
```

What is the most efficient way to create all 128 unique parameter AClass(es)?

Edited: Mistakenly started at 0000001 instead of 1000000

Comment: Can't you use binary? (with some clever formatting that should do it)

Comment: Your probably right, I should be able to figure it out as well, bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` and `String.format` to complete your String with 0 in left:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%07d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i))));
}
```

This will show you :

```
0000000
0000001
...
...
1111110
1111111
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using binary representation:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            System.out.println(padLeft(Integer.toBinaryString(i), 8));
        }
    }

    // borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java
    public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
        return String.format("%1$" + n + "s", s).replace(' ', '0');  
    }
}
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/FQFtNY)