# how to combine 2 string using or operator?

Tags: java, binary

```
String a="b5a99e49708ecf072f189b4f85007c76990ef305";
String b="a7d55b1a392a1f34ab95453817fdd49df140c486";
```

Example i converted string to decimal "1". it was 6 bits. how do i do it 7bits? and use or operator string a and b;

Here is my code

```
char[] c = a.toCharArray();
char[] d = b.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    r += Integer.toBinaryString(c[i]|d[i]);     
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What results you expect?

Comment: `char` is a 16-bit data type, so "doing it" to 7 bits doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I suspect you're mostly asking [how to pad a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java) (e.g., with leading zeros on your binary string).

Comment: Those strings look like (long) hexadecimal numbers. Do you want the bitwise logical OR of those numbers?

Comment: character 1 decimal 49 binary 110001 6 bits i need 0110001

Comment: So the question, is it how to convert char `'1'` to the string `"0110001"`?

Comment: I have rewritten my answer after the new information.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you just need to prepend the correct number of zeroes to your binary string so there are 7 bits in all. The standard trick to generate a small fixed number of a character is to use `String.substring()` on a constant string of that character. Since a `char` fits in 16 bits, we will never need more than 16 zeroes:

```
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(ch);
    int missingZeroes = desiredNumberOfBits - binaryString.length();
    if (missingZeroes > 0) {
        binaryString = "0000000000000000".substring(0, missingZeroes) + binaryString;
    }
    System.out.println(binaryString);
```

If `ch` is a `char` holding a `1`, the above prints

```
0110001
```

You can fill in `c[i] | d[i]` instead of `ch` if that is what you require.

You may want to add a defensive check that the string from `Integer.toBinaryString()` is not already too long.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine these hexadecimal values as Strings this way.

```
char[] c = a.toCharArray();
char[] d = b.toCharArray();
char[] r = new char[Math.min(a.length, b.length)];
String hex = "0123456789abcdef";

for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    int ci = Character.getNumericValue(c[i]);
    int di = Character.getNumericValue(d[i]);
    int ri = ci | di;
    r[i] = hex.charAt(ri);
}
String s = new String(r);
```