# Integer to BinaryString removes leading zero in Java

Tags: java, binary

I wanted to convert an integer to binary string. I opted to use the native function that java allows `Integer.toBinaryString(n)`. But unfortunately, this trims the leading zero from my output. Lets say for example, I give the input as `18`, it gives me output of `10010` but the actual output is supposed to be `010010`. Is there a better/short-way to convert int to string than writing a user defined function? Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
int n = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to combine 2 string using or operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658281/how-to-combine-2-string-using-or-operator) (I know with that title it sounds crazy, but take a look at [my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43658944/5772882)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *its suppose to be **010010***....

not really, integer type have made up from 32 bits, so it *should* be:

***000000000000000000000000010010***, java is not going to print that information, left zeros are in this case not relevant for the magnitude of that number..

so you need to append the leading zeros by yourself, since that method is returning a string you can format that:

```
String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(18)).replace(' ', '0')
```

or in your case using 6 bits

```
String.format("%6s", Integer.toBinaryString(18)).replace(' ', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s

So no, you aren't doing something wrong. To get your desired output, you'll need to write a small method yourself. One way would be to prepare a string with zeros with the length of your desired output, substring it and append the value.
Like

```
private String getBinaryString6Bit(int n) {
    String binaryNoLeadingZero = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    return "000000"
            .substring(binaryNoLeadingZero.length())
            + binaryNoLeadingZero;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to add the leading zeros you can make a new string that puts zeros in the front the add the old string with binary at the end to get the leading zeros a example would look like this:

```
String binaryString = "";
int n = 126;
binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
String finalBinary = "";
for(int i = binaryString.length(); i < 8; i++) {
      finalBinary += "0";
    }
finalBinary += binaryString;
System.out.println(finalBinary);
```

This code will take 126 transfer it into binary then add any leading zeros that are missing which in this case would only be 1 leading zero.