# How to get Number pattern in specific shape (java)?

Tags: java, numbers

I want to print number pattern like this..

but, I failed to get this triangle shape,and I am confused how to put spaces to get this shape -->

```
   1
  212
 32123
4321234
```

Here's the code i tried so far

```
public class Ch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r =Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for(int u=1;u<=r;u++)
        { 
            for(int i=u;i>=1;i--)
            {
                System.out.print(i);
            }

            for(int i=2;i<=u;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output of this code looks-like this

```
     1
     212
     32123
     4321234
```

Thanks

Comment: What should happen when there will be let's say 20 lines? I mean what numbers should be displayed for line 10 and greater?

Comment: looks a lot like a homework question..

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more step in you main loop before the other two:

```
for (int i = u; i < r; i++)
{
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

This will print spaces to make up for the "missing" numbers.

In regard to Mateusz' comment, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391978/7653073) on how to pad your numbers with spaces to make them equally wide in case you go beyond 9:

```
static int padding;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    padding = Math.max(1, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(r)));

    for (int u = 1; u <= r; u++)
    {
        for (int i = u; i < r; i++)
        {
            print(" ");
        }

        for (int i = u; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            print(i);
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= u; i++)
        {
            print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
private static void print(Object text)
{
    System.out.print(String.format("%1$" + padding + "s", text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### using 2 for loops

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the pyramid limit value: ");
        int limit = in.nextInt();
        in.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < limit + i; j++) {
                if (j < limit -i-1)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else{               
                    int temp = (limit-j > 0) ? limit-j : j-limit+2;
                    System.out.print(temp);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

### }

### using 4 for loops

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the pyramid limit value: ");
        int limit = in.nextInt();
        in.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<limit-i; j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
                System.out.print(i-j+1);
            }
            for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
                System.out.print(i-j+2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```