# Java - Create a header using asterisk

Tags: java, methods

I have been trying to figure out this problem, any help would be appreciated. I am supposed to create a header of asterisks which is supposed to be a method like this:

[image]

I am completely stumped, I am able to create the two long lines of 60 asteriks and the left most 3 asteriks but can't get the last 3 or have any clue how to get the message to print.

this is what I have to print just the basic lines:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++){
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("\n***");     
for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++){
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");
```

which prints out:

[image]

Any help would be great.

Edited code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String msg = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int whiteSpace;


    System.out.println("Enter your message: ");
    msg = in.nextLine();

     if(msg.length() < 54)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("\n***");


         whiteSpace = (54 - (msg.length())/2);
         for (int x = 0; x<=whiteSpace; x++)
         {
         System.out.print(" ");
         }

         System.out.print(msg);

         for (int x = 0; x<=whiteSpace; x++)
         {
         System.out.print(" ");
         }

       System.out.print("\n***");

       for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++)
       {
           System.out.print("*");
       }
       System.out.println("");

}
```

}

and I get this:

[image]

Comment: What if the message length is odd?

Comment: you're missing a set of parentheses now. it needs to be (54-msg.length)/2 not 54-(msg.length/2)

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the entirety of your string and the tailing 3 *s.

you have 54 characters between the two sets of '***' so to center your string you need to take (54 - (string.length()))/2 and add this much white space at the beginning AND and of your string before finishing with the remaining 3 *s (you should also check that the string is a max of 54 characters.)

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++){
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("\n***");


//your code is missing this
int length=string.length()
int whiteSpace=(54 - (string.length()))/2)
for (int x = 0; x<=whiteSpace){
 System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.print(string);
for (int x = 0; x<=whiteSpace){
 System.out.print(" ");
}


System.out.print("\n***");
//up to here


for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++){
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: I intentionally left this a bit pedantic so you could see the linear translation of the idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! can you check my edited code in my post and tell me whats wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: @rKittle fixed in the comment on your question. but ill post here also. you're missing a set of parentheses now. it needs to be (54-msg.length)/2 not 54-(msg.length/2) .... so move the parenthesis before msg.length to before the 54:)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this approach to complete the task:

- Identify the line in your code that prints the middle three `***`
- You need to print `message` followed by another three `***` and `\n`
- The total number of characters on the middle line is 60, so the text in the middle has to be 54-characters long
- Therefore, `message` needs to be truncated at 54 characters
- Assume that the message is `N` characters long, where `N <= 54`
- Padding on the left is `padLeft = (54-N)/2`
- Padding on the right is `padRight = 54 - N - padLeft`
- After that the message needs to be padded on both sides until it is exactly 54-characters long
- Once you have your padded message, print `"***" + paddedMessage + "***"`

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388461/335858) for information on how to pad a `String` in Java.