# How do I use an input to out put exactly 5 characters in a string and space them out

Tags: java, string, printf, spacing

Basically I'm trying to make a code in Java where I am inputting 5 letters, for example "Hello". The code needs to spit an output with each of the letters spaced apart by ten spacing. I also have to use printf and space them out using the %. I was able to do this without using %, by using .replace, however that's not what I'm supposed to be doing.
So the output should be:
H     e    l     l      o

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter five chatracters: ");
String charoutput = scanner.next();
String charoutput2 = charoutput.replace("", "       ");

System.out.println("You have entered: " +charoutput2);
```

Comment: check out the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java to help with the space padding. as for the 5 letters i'd use a loop

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter five chatracters: ");

    // You can include validation of the length of the input line if necessary
    String answer = scanner.next();
    String[] charArr = answer.substring(0, 5).split("");
    String result = Arrays.stream(charArr)
            .map(p -> String.format("%s%10s", p, ""))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(result);
    scanner.close();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the entire question, you need to use `printf` as well.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting

Comment: If you want controlling length of string (and stream) - you may try next way : substring(0, answer.length()).split("");