# Excel sheet removing zero(s) for number starting with zero(s)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

I need to write `CSV`/`Xls` file with a column having numbers like `00078`, but even after writing the number as a string, excel sheet displays it as `78`.

**I have tried** `apache poi` library and try setting cell type to String.

```java
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 

// Create a blank sheet 
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("student Details"); 

// This data needs to be written (Object[]) 
Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>(); 
data.put("1", new Object[]{ "ID", "NAME", "LASTNAME" }); 
data.put("2", new Object[]{ 00078, "Pankaj", "Kumar" }); 

// Iterate over data and write to sheet 
Set<String> keyset = data.keySet(); 
int rownum = 0; 
for (String key : keyset) { 
    // this creates a new row in the sheet 
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++); 
    Object[] objArr = data.get(key); 
    int cellnum = 0; 
    for (Object obj : objArr) { 
        // this line creates a cell in the next column of that row 
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++); 
        if (obj instanceof String) 
            cell.setCellValue((String)obj); 
        else if (obj instanceof Integer){
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(obj));
        }
    } 
}
```

I expect the column to treat `00078` as a String and display the same.

Comment: Try `data.put("2", new Object[]{ "00078", "Pankaj", "Kumar" });` add quotes, you have it as a number there currently.

Comment: Great advice @Adder it worked. Now I wonder how did I not see it. But the problem is that the place I'm implementing this has object with this number as Integer type in it.

Comment: See [pad a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java) for how to pad a string - or just use a while loop to prepend zeroes till the width is reached.

Comment: `00078` as integer is removes automatically leading zeros. `00078` is the same as `78`. If you want leading zeros, store the value as String in java, or add them at a later point, but also as string

Comment: I successfully wrote a xls file with 00078 value but, when I edit the cell and then defocus, it goes back to 78.

Answer (score 1):

If a `ID` must have leading zeros, then data type of this `ID` must be `String`. Numbers do not have leading zeros. The number 000123 is mathematically exactly the same as 123.

Additional in case of `Excel` the cells containing this `ID` values should have cell styles of `Text` format. And to prevent changing the cell style to number style by editing the cell, additional the cell style should be quote prefixed. Else editing the cell may lead to the case that 000123 changes to 123 again.

The following code shows a complete example where the `ID` column is protected that way.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreateExcelSheetFromDataObjectArray {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
   new Object[]{"ID", "NAME", "LASTNAME", "AMOUNT", "DATE"},
   new Object[]{"000123", "John", "Doe", 1234.56, new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1) },
   new Object[]{"000456", "Jane", "Stiles", 7890.12, new GregorianCalendar(2019, 1, 11) },
   new Object[]{"000789", "Mary", "Major", 3456.78, new GregorianCalendar(2019, 2, 22) }
  };

  String filePath = "./Excel";

  String wantedXLFormat = 
   //"XSSF";
   "HSSF";

  try (Workbook workbook = ("XSSF".equals(wantedXLFormat))?new XSSFWorkbook():new HSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(filePath + (("XSSF".equals(wantedXLFormat))?".xlsx":".xls")) ) {

   DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("DDDD, MMMM, DD, YYYY"));
   CellStyle numberStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   numberStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00 \" Coins\""));

   // the cell style for the ID column has Text format and is quote prefixed
   CellStyle idStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   idStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("@"));
   idStyle.setQuotePrefixed(true);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);

     if (r == 0) cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]); // the header row, all columns are strings

     if (r > 0 && c == 0) { // the ID column
      cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(idStyle);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 3) { // the number column
      cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(numberStyle);
     } else if (r > 0 && c == 4) { // the date column
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)data[r][c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (r > 0) { // all other columns are strings
      cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]);
     }
    }
   }

   for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}
```

The code works tested using `apache poi 4.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess writing this would have caused **compilation error** -

> Integer number too large

```
data.put("2", new Object[]{ 00078, "Pankaj", "Kumar" });
```

In comments Adder has said it rightly

```
data.put("2", new Object[]{ "00078", "Pankaj", "Kumar" });
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: I successfully wrote a xls file with 00078 value but, when I edit the cell and then defocus, it goes back to 78.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prepend = sign before data.
Ex: `="00082"`

```
"=" + "\"0000882\""
```